# WFP dxg datagrid, select first row automatically with focus

Tags: wpf, datagrid, devexpress

```
<helpers:CustomGrid Grid.Row="0"
                    Margin="0"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="None"
                    x:Name="DataGrid"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                    CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentOrder}">

         <helpers:CustomGrid.View>
                    <dxg:TableView Name="TView"
                                   AllowResizing="True"
                                   NavigationStyle="Cell"
                                   ShowFixedTotalSummary="True" 
                                   AllowLeaveFocusOnTab="True" 
                                   HorizontalScrollbarVisibility="Auto" 
                                   VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Auto"/>
          </helpers:CustomGrid.View>
```

I can't find any property to set to get a row automatically, even tried in my customgrid:

```
public CustomGrid()
{
     ItemsSourceChanged += OnItemsSourceChanged;
}

private void OnItemsSourceChanged(object sender, ItemsSourceChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Orders is a ObservableCollection.

But it won't hit because I am adding range to my ObservableCollection and not creating a new (and thats how I want it)

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends but...  You could register to the Loaded event of the user control that contains your dataGrid and then perform a `BeginInvoke()` that sets the `CurrentOrder` on the view model and then again issue another `BeginInvoke()` to set focus.

Example:

```
public CustomGrid()
{
    Loaded += CustomGrid_Loaded;
}

    void CustomGrid_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() =>
       {

           var vm = DataContext as PageViewModel;
           vm.CurrentOrder = vm.Orders[0];

           //now set focus..
           dataGrid.Focus();   //sometimes you may need to issue another BeginInvoke() when you hijack the event model
```

Comment: tried it, it won't hit on loaded, put breakpoint to see, did as you wrote, mabye I forgot something?

Comment: you see the OnLoaded event get registered?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a focused row when the `GridControl` is rendered, you can set [DataControlBase.AllowInitiallyFocusedRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataControlBase.AllowInitiallyFocusedRow.property) to true.

```
<helpers:CustomGrid Grid.Row="0"
                    Margin="0"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="None"
                    x:Name="DataGrid"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                    CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentOrder}"
                    AllowInitiallyFocusedRow="True">
```

If you want to have the first row selected anytime the `GridControl` gets focused, you can do it with a custom `TableView` implementation (or Behavior).

```
public class CustomTableView : TableView
{
    protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);

        if (FocusedRowHandle < 0)
            FocusedRowHandle = (DataControl as GridControl).GetRowHandleByListIndex(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this, but got the member AllowInitiallyFocusedRow is not recognized or accessible, am I missing something?

Comment: It is part of DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v18.2.Core.dll, add this dll to your project. Right-click on your project, choose Add -> Reference... and then select Browse tab and click Browse button. The dll is usually located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 18.2\Components\Bin\Framework` on Windows.

Comment: aha I see, I am on 16.2 right now, I will uppgrade it in the future, can't right now (big solution). but the moment I will uppgrade I will try this solution, thank you very much for your help =))

Comment: This property might be available in 16.2, I can't check. If you're using Visual Studio, create a dummy class that inherits from Table View, in the constructor type `AllowInitiallyFocusedRow`, it will come up as an error, place cursor on `AllowInitiallyFocusedRow` and  press `CTRL` + `.`, if this property exists in one of DevExpress dll, it will come up as a suggestion.

Comment: I tried and did not get suggestion from devexpress, but thanks for the thought, it was a good try =))